# How to get the first column value through values of the second column

Tags: java, database, jpa

I want to get the first column value by looking after the second column value.

The problems that could occur are the following: 
 1. there is a one to many relation between the first column data and the second column data (therefore I have to use the @OneToMany I guess in that class where I have my get- and set-methodes? )
 2. the where clause if I will use a Query (as far as I understood my first language is not English, I have to use namedQueries since the find() method is just for looking up things I directly know) should be dynamic, I explain this in short: I want to provide a service in which via HTTP request someone types in the value of the 2nd column and then with that value I would like to look up the value of the first column

My following solution idea:

`customers = em.createNamedQuery("findAllCustomersWithName")
            .setParameter("custName", "Smith")
            .getResultList();`

so the problem with that is that I want to be that setParamter dynamic so that "Smith" depends on that HTTP request so I would like to have there a reference for example customerName which will be coupled with the HTTP request so this would depend on what the User types in the UI ... I have no idea how this is possible I hope you understood my problem

Comment: "I hope you understood my problem" - actually - no. I see two questions here: 1. How to perform a database query using jpa. 2. How to get a value to be used as parameter from the UI / out of HTTP request. Which one is it?

Comment: @Fildor its the second one mostly

Comment: So this one is what I really want or better tried but it doesnt work, I want to get the customerName via looking up a customerId which comes from the UI out of HTTP request, and as I said a Customer could have multiple customerId's..... `public Customer getCustomerHelper(String custName) {
   
   this.getEntityManager();
   return em.find(Customer.class, customerId);
  }`

Comment: @illgoforit first of all how do I pass that value? then I explain to you my problem

Comment: em.createNamedQuery("findAllCustomersWithName")
            .setParameter("custName", httpRequest.getParameter("customerName"))
            .getResultList(); ... but if u cant figure that out on your own i think you have gone too far away with using jpa, http requests and whatever else you are using, you miss the basics

Comment: @illgoforit Okay cool I wasn't sure if that is allowed so thanks for that mate..... now to my bigger Problem I want to get the customerName through the httpRequest with an customerId so this is not anymore the same mapping since the customerName is in the first column and the cardId's are all on the second column I guess this wont work:                                         em.createNamedQuery("findAllCustomersWithName") .setParameter("custName", httpRequest.getParameter("customerId")) .getResultList();